# ¿Cómo puedo encontrar el número de veces que se repite una palabra acabada en *.. en un dataframe?

Tags: python, visual-studio, string, pandas, dataframe

Me gustaría saber cuántas veces se repite las palabras acabadas en *.. en un dataframe de dos columnas. Me interesaría saber cuántas veces se repite en una de las columnas.
Tengo esta parte de código pero me da error:

```
df2 = df_pr['transcript'].str.count('*..')
```

Pero me sale este error: nothing to repeat at position 0.

Me imagino que será por estar acabado en *.. y no ser un string. Cómo podría solucionar este error? Cómo podría hacerlo con la librería re o contra librería?

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

El asterizco es un caracter especial, por lo cual debes utilizar `\*` si deseas utilizarlo dentro del método `count()`

```
df2 = df_pr['transcript'].str.count('\*..')
```

Si deseas saber el total de coincidencias por columna puedes agregar el método `sum()`

```
df2 = df_pr['transcript'].str.count('\*..').sum()
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, me ha servido de gran ayuda. Un saludo!! @HeytalePazguato